# Returning an array of inner structs of a struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How can I return an array of child structs of a parent struct?

as an example: After pushing multiple chapters into the parent struct, how can I retrieve all the child structs as an array (or something else suitable)?

```
contract NewBook {

    struct ChapterData {
        // string chapterID;
        string title;
        uint pages;
    }

    struct BookData {
        // string bookID;
        ChapterData[] chapters;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => BookData) books; // bookId => BookData

    function addChapter(bytes32 _bookID, string memory title, uint pages) public {
        ChapterData memory c = ChapterData({
            title: title,
            pages: pages
        });
        books[_bookID].chapters.push(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you'll need to make use of Solidity's experimental ABI encoder, like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
...
```

You can then create a getter function that returns an array of structs:

```
function getChapterByBook(bytes32 memory _bookID) 
public 
view 
returns(
    ChapterData[] memory chapters
){
    return books[_bookID].chapters;
}
```